# How to set fixed height of the react-native-overlay-section?

Tags: javascript, react-native, bottom-sheet

I am using react-native-overlay-section. The bottom sheet is swipeable to the whole window but I want it to be swipeable to a particular height. How should I do? I have uploaded the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet

} from 'react-native';
import SlideUp from 'react-native-overlay-section';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }

    exampleContent = () => {
        return (
            <View >
                <Text>This is test text</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Text>Hello</Text>

                <SlideUp 

                contentSection={this.exampleContent()}

                draggableHeight={50} 

                />

            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },


});
```